# is google ml kit only front-end service?

Tags: flutter, computer-vision, google-mlkit

is google ml kit only front-end service ? I mean it only detect objects in an image or it go to the database and get the similar products as the captured one in flutter app?

Comment: Can you clarify by "google ml kit", do you mean ML Kit SDK (g.co/mlkit) or the flutter plugging (https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit)? If you are asking about the former, its Object Detection and Tracking API is for detecting objects in an image (or video) and does not go to a database to get the similar products. If you are asking about the latter, you could post your question in their support page (https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues).

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes i mean Ml Kit Sdk, so i guess i should use cloud vision api to do that for me 'get similar products from database' right? or there's something different ?

Comment: Yeah, Google Cloud Vision API Product Search seems to provide what you need: https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs